# Chunked Encoding vs writing on HttpServletResponse outputStream?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, ioutils

What benefit does chunked encoding provide over directly writing on the HttpServletResponse output stream in small chunks?

So doing something like the code shown below where the full file content is not being buffered in the app-memory vs sending with chunked encoding header. I'm using IoUtils.copy below which will only read 8K bytes from the input stream at a time.

```
@GetMapping("/content")
public void getContent(final HttpServletRequest request,
                        final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try(final InputStream is = FileUtils.openInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/test_file.txt"))) {
        //Do something with is
        response.setHeader("ContentType", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
        response.setContentLength(70000);
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't use chunked or fixed-length transfer encoding the full file content *is* buffered in memory, as `HttpServletResponse` has to fill in the `Content-length` header before it sends any content.

Comment: Your response makes sense. My question was incomplete though - edited it now. I did mean to provide a content-length header. My intention was to understand the difference when a fixed content-length header is provided and output stream is copied using small buffer size vs a response with chunked header.

Comment: It will ignore your `Content-length` header and behave as I described. The correct way to do what you are attempting is to call `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()`, but you better supply the right length.

Comment: I have been running some tests and I don't see this behavior. The callers get content-length as 0 and the file gets downloaded fine. 100s of concurrent requests and no OOM errors.

Comment: So you must be using either chunked streamingmode or `Connection: close`.